# I would like to remove the decimal point in javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, decimal, point

I would like to remove the decimal point in javascript / jquery

my code:

```
var comp2 = 35.99 * 10003;
var comp2gtotal;

comp2gtotal = comp2;
$(".comp2totaled").html( comp2gtotal );

<div class="comp2totaled"></div>
```

The answer i get is `360007.97000000003`

What i need it to say is = `360007.97` or `360,007.97`
without all the zeros ect at the end..

thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
comp2gtotal = Math.round(comp2 * 100) / 100;
$(".comp2totaled").html(comp2gtotal);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/A8E9g/1/)

Or if don't want to round the 3+ decimal places then

```
$(".comp2totaled").html(comp2gtotal.toFixed(2));
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/A8E9g/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 parseInt(comp2,10)
```

That will convert it to a decimal int

Answer (score 0):

[toFixed()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp)

Try this method.  It will help you.